# Removing some characters from cell values in a column by index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove some characters from 'name' columns, in a way to keep the very first characters and remove the rest

So this is my data:

```
   name   id
0  ABC-G  3
1  ERT-R  4
2  IGF    2
```

The result should be:

```
   name   id
0  AB     3
1  ER     4
2  IG     5
```

Comment: So the first two?

Comment: `df.name.str[:2]`

Comment: The dupe is how to extract `8`, but should be straightforward to change for `2`

Comment: thanks for you answer ,

Comment: Yes i need to keep the very first characters

Answer (score -1):

You can [**`str.slice(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) the column, like:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.slice(stop=2)
```

Or if you use some sort of filtering:

```
df.loc[some_filter, 'name'] = df[some_filter]['name'].str.slice(stop=2)
```

Comment: ":\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" this is the message  i get when i tap this  command

Comment: @zahirsafaa: yes, that is a common warning. Did you by any chance used a filter on this line? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/67579